# Is it a good idea to add robots "noindex" meta tags to deep low content pages, e.g. product model data

Tags: seo, noindex

I'm considering adding robots "noindex, follow" tags to the very numerous product data pages that are linked from the product style pages in our online store.

For example, each product style has a page with full text content on the product:

http://www.shop.example/Product/Category/Style/SOME-STYLE-CODE

Then many data pages with technical data for each model code is linked from the product style page.

http://www.shop.example/Product/Category/Style/SOME-STYLE-CODE-1
http://www.shop.example/Product/Category/Style/SOME-STYLE-CODE-2
http://www.shop.example/Product/Category/Style/SOME-STYLE-CODE-3

It is these technical data pages that I intend to add the no index code to, as I imagine that this might stop these pages from cannibalizing keyword authority for more important content rich pages on the site.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like one way, and possibly the ideal depending on what's on those `code-1` type pages, would be to actually consolidate the information into a single page, rather than have it spread over multiple pages.

Alternatively, if there's some good reason to keep those separate pages separate (e.g., they're full of long, dry specifications that would clutter the main page), then consolidate the whole group of pages by using [canonical link elements](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) on the `code-1` type pages pointing back to the main page. So:

`/some-style-code-1` and 
`/some-style-code-2` etc., would each have:

`<link rel="canonical" href="/some-style-code/" />` in the `<head>`.

That tells – well, *asks* – search engines to consolidate all the related pages together, and to always return the "main" page (the target of the canonical link element) as a search result.

So, to answer your actual question, about using `noindex` on those pages, I personally wouldn't. The canonical link element provides the same basic solution – not having those "product model data" pages appear as search results, while having the advantage of not throwing away whatever value those pages might have.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that each URL parameter -1, -2, -3 is created from pagination of your data pages? If so I would imagine the content is unique on all these pages. I would allow Google to index them and add a link or two through out the content on all these pages. Not going overboard but a single link or two every few pages can help build internal links. Look at how Zappos does it. They ad links in their content across their domain.

Comment: This isn't pagination, these are individual pages for each model, but all there is on the page is a small amount of technical data. There isn't really any content with which I can add contextual links.

Comment: what is a difference between one model and another, a color, size etc?